# Can Julia pass an argument to an inner anonymous function?

Tags: python, julia, parameter-passing, anonymous-function

I'm trying to pass an argument to an anonymous function in `map()` in a particular way (see code examples).

The following code in Julia...

```
function f(x,y):map((z)->z+y,x) end
print(f([1,2,3],1))
```

returns:

```
MethodError: objects of type Symbol are not callable
Stacktrace:
 [1] f(x::Vector{Int64}, y::Int64)
   @ Main .\REPL[1]:1
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

Same code translated to Python...

```
def f(x,y):
    return map(lambda z:z+y,x)
print(list(f([1,2,3],1)))
```

works as expected:
`[2, 3, 4]`.

Why is the same block of code misbehaving in Julia in contrast to Python and what is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a syntax issue: Julia function declarations don't use a colon before the function body.

```
julia> function f(x,y) map((z)->z+y,x) end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> print(f([1,2,3],1))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Or more readably,

```
julia> function f(x, y)
         map(z -> z .+ y, x)
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> print(f([1,2,3],1))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It would be good, if Julia enforced omission of the colon. I was getting `f (generic function with 2 methods)` after `function f(x,y): map((z)->z+y,x) end` (with the colon included ) which caught me off-guard.

Comment: Which version of Julia are you on? I'm on the latest (1.7), and any way I try it (with or without newline, extra spaces, etc.) ,that syntax (with the colon) gives an error for me.

Comment: Julia (Version 1.7.2).

Comment: I've tried on both 1.7.1 and 1.7.3 and get "ERROR: syntax" in both cases. Could you try again and make sure what you've pasted is what you tried? If it does work with the colon, without error, a screenshot would be appreciated too.

Comment: `function f(x,y):map((z)->z+y,x) end` does _not_ give a syntax error for me on 1.7.2. But with a space: `function f(x,y): map((z)->z+y,x) end` I do get a syntax error. Not sure what the OP means by 'enforced omission', though.

Comment: @DNF They mean it should be a syntax error, which it is in the spaced case. Wtihout the space, `:map` gets parsed as a Symbol, so syntactically it's valid, but there's the "objects of type Symbol are not callable" error mentioned in the question when you try to execute the function. So in either case it's not valid executable code.

Comment: It seems reasonable to require some kind of space between the end of the arguments and the function body, which would disallow the colon right after. technically breaking but I can’t see it being done in real world code. If someone wants to open an issue, It could be discussed.

Comment: @DNF Yes, I meant to say `function f(x,y):map((z)->z+y,x) end` and not `function f(x,y): map((z)->z+y,x) end` outputs `f (generic function with 2 methods)`. `f(x,y): map`  instead of `f(x,y):map` was a typo on my first comment. Like you I get a syntax error with `function f(x,y): map((z)->z+y,x) end`. I hadn't written a script in Julia for so long so I got the function syntax of Python and Julia confused. That's what led to my question on here.